# Decoding Base64 in only a portion of a JSON file with Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I am making an API call on one of my vendor's applications via powershell. The response from the API is a JSON file. Only a portion of the JSON file is encoded in BASE64. Is there a way to read the JSON file with powershell and decode the section that is encoded in BASE64? Example of the JSON file:

I can manually copy the "meta" data from the json file and decode it with powershell using the following code:

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("BASE64DATA"))
```

however when I try to pass in the JSON file instead of the copied text I get an error.

```
{
results: [
      {
        "id": "<Plain Text Data>",
        "meta": "<BASE64 Encoded Data>",
        "info": "<Plain Text Data>"
      },
     {  
       "id": "<Plain Text Data>",
       "meta": "<BASE64 Encoded Data>",
       "info": "<Plain Text Data>"
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is the JSON data actually a file or in the body of the HTTP response? (Assuming the API is RESTful)

Comment: Yes it is a RESTful API. The data is coming back in the body but am having it output it to a file so I can hopefully parse the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the json as an object, then convert it, decode and convert back to json.

```
$Json = Get-Content -Path c:\JsonFilePath.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$NewJson = $Json.Results | Foreach-Object -Process {
            $Converted = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($_.meta))
            $_.meta = $Converted
}
$NewJson | ConvertTo-Json
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with a RESTful API that returns JSON I recommend using the Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet to pull the data, it will automatically parse the JSON for you into an object.

Below is an example of how this would be done.

```
$json = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://something'
$json.results | ForEach-Object { $_.meta = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($_.meta)) }
$json.results
```

It will connect, pull the JSON data, and convert it to an object in the first command

The second command will convert the base64 encodings to plain text.

The third command will output the data for you to validate that this is working as expected.

Comment: For some reason when I try this I get an error: "The property "meta" cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

Comment: if you type just `$json.results` what is the output?

Comment: When I type $json.results, the output is blank

Comment: If the response body matches what is in the question it should work. Sadly without knowing what the body of the rest response looks like I'm unsure how to help further. :(